# Tem como matar uma thread em Python?

Tags: python, thread

Existe alguma forma de parar uma thread em python? E é uma má praticas fazer isso?

Comment: pergunta e resposta copiadas e coladas do SO Inglês seria no minimo justo dar credito a quem perguntou/respondeu....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É uma má pratica parar de forma abruptamente uma thread em qualquer linguagem.

Vamos pensar
A thread está com algum recurso critico que precisa ser fechado de forma correta.
A thread tem outras threads que devem ser paradas junto com essa thread.

A melhor maneira de lidar com isso se você puder, (se você está administrando suas próprias threads) é ter uma flag exit_request que cada thread checa regularmente para ver se é hora de fechar.

Vamos para um exemplo:

```
import threading

class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread class com metodo de stop(). A thread precisa checar 
    regularmente pela condição de stopped() ."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(StoppableThread, self).__init__()
        self._stop = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop.isSet()
```

Há casos, no entanto, quando você realmente precisa matar uma thread. Um exemplo é quando você está fazendo o wrap de uma biblioteca externa que está ocupada e você deseja interrompê-la.

O exemplo a seguir permite que (com algumas restrições) lance uma exceção em uma thread do Python:

```
def _async_raise(tid, exctype):
    '''Lanca uma excecao na threads com id tid'''
    if not inspect.isclass(exctype):
        raise TypeError("Somente tipos podem ser lancados (nao instancias)")
    res = ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(tid,
                                                  ctypes.py_object(exctype))
    if res == 0:
        raise ValueError("thread com invalido id")
    elif res != 1:
        # "Se lancar um numero maior que um, eh um problema,
        # e voce deveria chamar novamente com exc=NULL para reverter o efeito"
        ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(tid, 0)
        raise SystemError("PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc falhou")

class ThreadWithExc(threading.Thread):
    def _get_my_tid(self):
        if not self.isAlive():
            raise threading.ThreadError("the thread is not active")

        if hasattr(self, "_thread_id"):
            return self._thread_id

        for tid, tobj in threading._active.items():
            if tobj is self:
                self._thread_id = tid
                return tid

        # TODO: em python 2.6, existe uma forma mais simples : self.ident

        raise AssertionError("nao pode determinar as threads com id")

    def raiseExc(self, exctype):
        _async_raise( self._get_my_tid(), exctype )
```

Conforme observado, isto não é perfeito, porque se a thread estiver ocupada fora do interpretador Python, não vai pegar a interrupção.